# Postfix defers mails - Amavis not running on port 10024

Tags: linux, debian, postfix, amavis

I recently upgraded from Debian Squeeze (6) to Jessie (8) and the mail server seems to be broken. I did not change anything in the Postfix config and everything was working fine before. From what I read on SO and forums, it might be that Amavis is not running on port 10024 :

```
[...] status=deferred (connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
```

If I run the following command:

```
netstat -ntlp
```

I do not see anything running on port 10024 (or even 110 and 587 which Postfix was using prior to the update).

I can restart Amavis and Postfix without any problem or error.
I do not know what to try next and I would be very grateful to anybody that would have an idea of something to try.

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
always_add_missing_headers = yes
always_bcc = mailarchive@localhost
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 0
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
owner_request_special = no
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 20
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 0
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
```

master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================

amavis unix - - n - 2 smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - n - - smtpd
  -o content_filter=amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
  -o smtpd_milters=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
587      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       permit_sasl_authenticated
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap

smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# 2016-10-12 : Ajouté comme workaround de Gmail qui rejete les courriels
smtp4     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp -o inet_protocols=ipv4
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
    -o smtp_fallback_relay=

# 2015-04-28 - Config ci-dessus remplacée par ceci :
# (pour changer l'IP d'envoi)
# smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#         -o smtp_bind_address=XXXXXXXXX
# # When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
# relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#         -o smtp_bind_address=XXXXXXXXX
#         -o smtp_fallback_relay=

# /2015-04-28 - Fin du remplacement

#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5

showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
# ajouté - 2015-04-22
polite unix - - n - - smtp
turtle unix - - n - - smtp
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
# amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
#         -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
#         -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
#
# 127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd
#         -o content_filter=
#         -o local_recipient_maps=
#         -o relay_recipient_maps=
#         -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
#         -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
#         -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#         -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
#         -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
#         -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
#         -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
#         -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
#         -o smtpd_bind_address=127.0.0.1

#
# Slow - config MX Orange/Wanadoo
#
# slow    unix    -       -       n       -       5       smtp
#    -o syslog_name=postfix-slow
#    -o smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=3
#    -o slow_destination_rate_delay=1

scan      unix  -       -       n       -       16      smtp
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
127.0.0.1:10026 inet  n -       n       -       16      smtpd
    -o content_filter=amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks_style=host
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8

127.0.0.1:12502 inet    n    -    n    -    -    smtpd
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o local_header_rewrite_clients=
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o smtpd_milters=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

This is /var/log/syslog on Postfix startup:

```
Mar 14 18:24:21 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Stopping Mail Transport Agent.
Mar 14 18:24:21 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Mar 14 18:24:21 ks4000003 postfix/master[13883]: terminating on signal 15
Mar 14 18:24:21 ks4000003 postfix[14599]: Stopping Postfix Mail Transport Agent: postfix.
Mar 14 18:24:21 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Mar 14 18:24:22 ks4000003 postfix[14624]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent: postfix.
Mar 14 18:24:22 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Mar 14 18:24:22 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Starting Mail Transport Agent.
Mar 14 18:24:22 ks4000003 systemd[1]: Reached target Mail Transport Agent.
Mar 14 18:24:22 ks4000003 postfix/master[14732]: daemon started -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
```

This is the output of service postfix status:

```
* postfix.service - LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/postfix)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/postfix.service.d
           `-50-postfix-$mail-transport-agent.conf
   Active: active (running) since jeu. 2019-03-14 18:24:22 EDT; 2min 58s ago
  Process: 14599 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4695 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/postfix reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14624 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           |-14732 /usr/lib/postfix/master
           |-14741 pickup -l -t fifo -u -c
           |-14742 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
           |-14753 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u -c
           |-16358 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -c -o stress= -s 2
           |-16359 proxymap -t unix -u
           `-16363 anvil -l -t unix -u -c
```

Comment: Is the amavis service even enabled or running?

Comment: I edited question's details to show log on startup and postfix status (seems to be running)

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that all messages go to the queue (at least...), if that helps

Comment: Amavis https://docs.iredmail.org/debug.amavisd.html, 
clamav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334100/where-is-my-clamav-log, spamassassin https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/spamassassin/HowToDebug -  logs were needed for troubleshooting.